# CardView with a fixed amount of children

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, cardview

I want an Activity that shows exactly four cards (never more or less) with the same layout as you can see in the image below. Can I implement this without using the, imo rather complex, RecyclerView and without the just copy & pasting xml four times? It is also important that I can access and change each of the views by id.

I currently have four CardViews stacked on top of each other and it feels very wrong. How should I be doing this?

[image: How it should look like]

Here is the bad XML code I used for the mockup above. I put it into an snippet since it is rather long and probably not very important to the question:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LobbyActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/player1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/player2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.95">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/player1Info"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="Playername - 100(+3)"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/player1Thumb"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/player1Ready"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="Ready: true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="#8A000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/player1Thumb"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/player1Info" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/player1Thumb"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/player2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/player3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/player1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.95">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/player2Info"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="Playername - 100(+3)"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/player2Thumb"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/player2Ready"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="Ready: true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="#8A000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/player2Thumb"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/player2Info" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/player2Thumb"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/player3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/player4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/player2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.95">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/player3Info"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="Playername - 100(+3)"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/player3Thumb"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/player3Ready"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="Ready: true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="#8A000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/player3Thumb"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/player3Info" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/player3Thumb"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/player4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/player3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.95">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/player4Info"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="Playername - 100(+3)"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/player4Thumb"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/player4Ready"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="Ready: true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="#8A000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/player4Thumb"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/player4Info" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/player4Thumb"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: yes. you can do that.

Comment: You can do whatever you want, nobody can prohibit you from that.

Comment: @KaranMer But how can I do it using one CardView instead of four?

Comment: the way you have created xml, is it generating error when you try implementing your logic? what is the problem if you use your proposed solution?

Comment: It's possible with Java code.

Comment: @KaranMer it feels like it shouldn't be done this way. I have basically the same code four times which sounds like bad practice tbh

Comment: it is not bad practice at all, you have fixed requirements and the proposed model solves it effectively. It would be just repetative if there are chagnes

Comment: See [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465) tutorial.

Comment: @MiXT4PE why can't you use recyclerview, because you just provide the data in arraylist, since it works depending on array size you only need to make one of those cardview

Comment: @JinsLukose I could use it. I would like to avoid it since it is a lot of code for something so simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the card view looks the same, you can create a separate reusable layout with only one CardView in it. Then, you can use the `<include>` tag to add it 4 times. This way, if you ever need to change the look of it, you only do it once.

More info on how to achieve this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts).

**Example**

```
<include 
   android:id="@+id/news_title" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   layout="@layout/title"/>
```

**NB:** you can differentiate each included element by setting a an `id`, just like in the example above.

To get a child view, you will need its id. First, use the  id to retrieve a the View (or CardView or...). For example:

```
CardView card1 = view.findViewById(cardView1);
card1.findViewById(player1Info);
```

Same with the next included card:

```
CardView card2 = view.findViewById(cardView2);
card2.findViewById(player1Info); //Notice how it is the same id here <------
```

Comment: So I would just include the same layout four times? How would I be able to get the fields? Won't they all have the same view ids?

Comment: i think so `<merge/>` would be better option in your case.

Comment: @AliAhmed Could you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: You can give each element a different id. Here is an example from the link in the answer above:

   `<include android:id="@+id/news_title"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         layout="@layout/title"/>`

Comment: @Ariles So if I include the same layout four times and give each include an id. How can I separately access the first TextView of include 1 and include 2?

Comment: @MiXT4PE you will need the child id. First, use the <include> id to retrieve a the `View` (or CardView or...), for example: CardView **card1** = view.findViewById(cardView1); Then: card1.findViewById(**player1Info**);

Same with the next included card: CardView **card2** = view.findViewById(cardView1); Then: card2.findViewById(**player1Info**);

Comment: @Ariles Thank you very much! You should edit this in

Comment: @MiXT4PE done ! I made a mistake in my last comment: the id for the cardView is different each time (cardView1 vs cardView2).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. 
Recycler view do not give you any advantages in your case.

But do not forget create `style` or use `<include>`.

It will help you if design will be changed in the future

In your case I recomend to use `include`. You can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts). The main idea is to create aditional cardview_layout.xml and use

> ```
> <include layout="@layout/cardview_layout"/>
> ```

in your main xml file.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use those? Can I just include the same layout four times? How would I be able to get the fields? Won't they all have the same view ids?

Comment: Thanks! How will I be able to access the views by id?

Comment: @MiXT4PE `include` supports adding `id` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts) `<merge/>` is used when you don't need extra View groups for good UI performance.

> The  tag helps eliminate redundant view groups in your view hierarchy when including one layout within another. For example, if your main layout is a vertical LinearLayout in which two consecutive views can be re-used in multiple layouts, then the re-usable layout in which you place the two views requires its own root view. However, using another LinearLayout as the root for the re-usable layout would result in a vertical LinearLayout inside a vertical LinearLayout. The nested LinearLayout serves no real purpose other than to slow down your UI performance.

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/add"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/delete"/>

</merge>
```

> Now, when you include this layout in another layout (using the `<include/>` tag), the system ignores the `<merge>` element and places the two buttons directly in the layout, in place of the `<include/>` tag.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `RecyclerView` use [`GridLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)  to achieve this

```
List<String> dataSource = new ArrayList<String>();


RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    recyclerView.setLayoutParams(lp);


    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 4, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    setContentView(recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new TextRecyclerAdapter(dataSource));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

[here is git example for this](https://github.com/Mogikan/Stackoverflow-samples)

Answer (score 0):

use a `LinearLayout` ... optionally, convert to 4 times `include`, with unique `id` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"/>
    </android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>

    <android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"/>
    </android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>

    <android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"/>
    </android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>

    <android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"/>
    </android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>

</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

this looks quite alike what you have there:

[image: XML preview screenshot]